# How to search for rdfs:labels in dbpedia which are partial matches to a given term using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdfs, sparqlwrapper

I am using this query to search for all labels that contains the word "Medi"

```
select distinct ?label where 
{ 
    ?concept rdfs:label  ?label 
    filter contains(?label,"Medi") 
    filter(langMatches(lang(?label),"en")) 
}
```

However, as soon as I change the term from "Medi" to "Medicare" it doesn't work and times out. How do I get it to work with longer words like Medicare i.e. extract all labels which has the word Medicare in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query has to iterate over all labels in DBpedia - which is quite a large number - and then apply String containment check. This is indeed expensive.

Even a count query leads to an "estimated timeout error":

```sql
select count(?label) where 
{ 
    ?concept rdfs:label  ?label 
    filter(regex(str(?label),"Medi")) 
    filter(langMatches(lang(?label),"en")) 
}
```

Two options:

1. Virtuoso has some fulltext search support:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT ?label WHERE { 
     ?concept rdfs:label ?label .
     ?label bif:contains "Medicare"
     FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"en"))
   }
   ```
2. Since the public DBpedia endpoint is a shared endpoint, the solution is to load the DBpedia dataset into your own triple store, e.g. Virtuoso. There you can adjust the max. estimated execution timeout parameter.

Comment: Hi, 
I am actually running dbpedia on a local server. And I'd prefer a faster solution, cause being slow would mean bad UX.

So, I copy-pasted your Option #1. And got back this : 
`Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: syntax error at '?label' before 'bif:contains'

SPARQL query:
define sql:big-data-const 0 
#output-format:text/html
define sql:signal-void-variables 1 SELECT DISTINCT ?label WHERE { 
  ?concept rdfs:label  ?label 
 ?label bif:contains "Medicare"
 FILTER(langMatches(lang(?label),"en"))
}`
Could you please help me debug :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot the dot after the first triple pattern. Should work now.